# How to make kubernetes not kill pods that consume too much memory

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Kubernetes job with container memory limits. For e.g:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Job
metadata:
 name: example-job
spec:
 containers:
 - name: example-container-name
   image: someimage
   resources:
     limits:
       memory: "1Gi"
```

However, if the container consumes more memory than 1GB it gets `OOMKILLED`. I can't control how much memory my application takes, is there a way to prevent Kubernetes kill the pod and instead limit its memory usage? I want the behavior to be similar to that of a personal computer - if you use too much memory everything becomes slower (due to swapping for e.g), but the process is not killed by the OS normally.

Comment: Impossible to help here - you have not provided a minimum reproducible example. The only way to resolve is to increase memory assigned to the box and hope you don't have a memory leak, or monitor and optimise you appilcation (which no details are provided for)

Comment: If you do not have enough physical memory or swap, even on a desktop system the kernel will be forced to kill arbitrary processes.  You can get this behavior on Kubernetes by deleting the `resources:` block, but in practice this might make your process _more_ likely to get OOM killed.

Answer (score 2):

It happened because your application took more than 1 GB memory, and you did limit your pod with 1 GB max, so when your application consumes more than 1 GB Memory your application will be killed by Kubernetes, so the best action is make your application resource usage more effective or increase your limit.

**Additional tips**: if you had more than 1 container in your pod you need to consider the other container memory usage. it happens if you have a sidecar container or mutating webhook.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the resource limits in your descriptor, you are **telling** Kubernetes to kill your pod if you exceed that limit.  So as other people have said, remove the limit, raise the limit or make your code more efficient.  Those are the only options you have.